# MVVM cross picture chooser plugin for iOS UI does not update using InMemoryImage on a Bytes type view model property

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am building a cross platform Xamarin solution, using separate iOS / android projects with a shared PCL containing view models written using MVVM cross (version 3.5.1 of the framework and the plugin).

I am using the iOS device camera to take a picture and storing the value in a Bytes variable like this:

```
    private byte[] _bytes;

    public byte[] Bytes {
        get { return _bytes; }
        set {
            _bytes = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => Bytes); 
        }
    }

    public void TakePhoto ()
    {
            var task = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask> ();
            task.TakePicture (500, 90,
                stream => {
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
                    stream.CopyTo (memoryStream);
                    Bytes = memoryStream.ToArray ();
                },
                () => {
                    // perform any cancelled operation
                });
    }
```

The camera opens correctly on the click of a bound button, and allows me to take a picture, but the image view in my UI does not update after I select to "use" the photo I took.

Here is my binding:

```
        set.Bind(imgPhoto).To(vm => vm.Bytes).WithConversion("InMemoryImage");
        set.Bind (btnTakePhoto).To ("TakePhoto");
```

Where imgPhoto is

`public MvxImageView imgPhoto { get; set; }`

and btnTakePhoto is

```
public UIButton btnTakePhoto { get; set; }
```

(I have tried my best to follow the binding syntax used in the MVVMcross N+17 tutorial on youtube - (Stuart if you're answering this, thanks for those!)

It works perfectly well on android using the same view model code and binding like this to the view:

```
local:MvxBind="Bitmap Bytes, Converter=InMemoryImage; Visible Bytes;"
```

I have added the referencing assemblies for the in memory conversion in the setup class of the app like this (which i didn't have to do for android):

```
    protected override List<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies {
        get {
            var toReturn = base.ValueConverterAssemblies;
            toReturn.Add(typeof(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Touch.MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter).Assembly);
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
```

And I added the picturechooser plugin via nuget so that I have the necessary bootstrap code included.

I have also tried this:

```
set.Bind(imgPhoto).For("Bitmap").To(vm => vm.Bytes).WithConversion("InMemoryImage");
```

And I've also tried using an MvxImageViewLoader and binding to that instead of directly to the MvxImageView, but no joy there either.

Finally I have also tried invoking the PictureChooserTask on the main thread, which also didn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a `UIImageView` the property is called `Image` and you have to bind like:

```
set.Bind(imgPhoto).For(v => v.Image).To(vm => vm.Bytes).WithConversion("InMemoryImage");
```

The default binding property is `ImageUrl`. But the `MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter` converts to an `UIImage`. That's why it has to get bound to `Image`.

Comment: For others: binding the original way I had without the  ("For") works fine if your picture is stored locally on the filesystem (and I think also a remote url), because the default binding is set to the ImageUrl property of the MvxImageView. You only seem to need to specify the 'Image' if you have an in memory image like I did